# Click once deployment restrict use to install on network folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have deploy a click once application on to a network folder.
This will also be the update path for click once application.
Now every user can access this path and click the exe to install the click once.

I want to make a authentication "pop up login dialog" using windows credential.
Example, user can click the exe, but it will prompt a login dialog, which need the IT department to login.

I am using VS 2012 express

How to achieve this implementation?

Comment: ClickOnce can't do this. Put the login dialog in your application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks. Have restrict user by putting security on the network folder

Comment: If my answer helped you, then leave it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the security on the network folder. Make sure only users you want to install the application have access to the folder.